# Polymer app routing partials with Page.js

Tags: polymer, page.js

I'm using the Polymer Starter Kit and would like have each route's content in a separate file (/pages/games.html, /pages/movies.html, etc) but I can't find any examples of this.

Could someone point me in the right direction? Or is it not possible or recommended to implement routing like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could approach this a lot of different ways (replacement of a holder in index.html at build time, swapping for a different router). One such approach would be to implement your files and then fetch() them into the DOM. This is sort of the approach that is used in the partials example that is outlined in page.js repo.

So, let's modify `iron-pages` in `index.html` in the starter kit to have a loading section:

```
<iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">

  <!-- Block we'll load our partials into -->
  <section id="load" data-route="load"></section>

...
```

Then let's modify `elements/routing.html` to change our page.js. Let's route `/test`  to our target load section:

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

  page('/test', function () {

    // iron-pages needs to show the proper section
    // in this case, our designated loading target
    app.route = 'load';

    // We include fetch.js polyfill in route.html for simplicity
    // 1. bower install fetch
    // 2. Add <script src="../../bower_components/fetch/fetch.js"></script> to routing.html
    fetch('/pages/test.html')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.text()
      }).then(function(body) {
        document.querySelector('#load').innerHTML = body;
      });
  });

  ...
```

We could then implement any amount of pages we want in `routing.html` that would load our html pages as needed.

Note, this basic approach doesn't take into account caching the response (back/forward would trigger the request again, which you probably don't want from a performance standpoint) and we're not catching our errors in the above example. But it's one such approach.

Comment: Thanks, that's sort of what I was looking for. However, how will templates and data-bindings work in /pages/test.html? I would imagine that we need to initialise everything in that page dynamically?

Comment: If you need bindings and templates then I'd approach this differently. I'd define my functionality as a custom element and then use the bindings and template ops that Polymer provides. This gives you a similar setup (code in separate file) without the need for AJAX (you'd simply define your tag in the section block and then navigate via the page.js router setup).

Comment: where is app defined at, I can't find it anywhere and have seen it multiple times online. i.e. app.route